# Make trigger update the rows I want

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am struggling with a trigger to update a second table based on the first table being updated.

I have tried this:

```
DELIMITER //
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Update phpfb_picks
set points = NEW.value
where username = user and gameid = gameid
END;
//
delimiter;
```

but get an error about syntax.

If I do:

```
Update phpfb_picks
set points = NEW.value
where username = user and gameid = gameid
```

This works to a point. It updates all users records with the same value that was updated.

What I want to do is, when a value is updated on Table A, I want to update Table B with all records for that user, basically the 'value' from table A would always be pushed to 'points' of table B for the user, regardless if the actual record was updated.

If any record for user is updated, update all of table B records with the same value based on the username and gameid

So if Table A has the following records:
username - test
gameid - 1
value - 1

username - test
gameid - 2
value - 2

when value from row 1 is updated to 3, i want to update Table B with all the current values from table A for that user.

Is this even possible?

UPDATE:

```
Table A (allpoints) has columns:
username
gameid
value

TABLE B (phpfb_picks) has columns:
user
gameid
points

allpoints.username = phpfb_picks.user
allpoints.gameid = phpfb_picks.gameid
allpoints.value = phpfb_picks.points
```

Whenever an update is made to allpoints, I want all the records for that specific user to update all the specific records for that user in phpfb_picks, passing the allpoints.value to phpfb_picks.points based on the user and gameid

Comment: Try telling the trigger to use new.user and new.gameid (assuming these are coming from the updated table) in the where statement.

Comment: Adding the NEW.user and NEW.gameid appears to make it so that it only updates the one record, now I need to know if there is a way, based on a single row update, to update all the records for that user. I can't seem to get the syntax right for FOR EACH ROW, which appears to be the option I need. Sorry, but I am very new to triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_phpfb_picks 
    AFTER UPDATE ON allpoints FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE phpfb_picks
        INNER JOIN allpoints ON allpoints.username = phpfb_picks.username AND
                                allpoints.gameid = phpfb_picks.gameid
        SET phpfb_picks.points = allpoints.value
        WHERE phpfb_picks.username = NEW.username;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For each row that is updated in `allpoints`, all rows in `phpfb_picks` with the same username of the updated row will be updated to the respective value of `points` present in `allpoints` as `value`. The trigger is an `AFTER UPDATE` so that the newly updated value in `allpoints` will also be set in `phpfb_picks`.

Comment: This has definitely produced better results, but for some reason, there is a scenario where field(s) are not being updated. This may be a timing issue or coding issue with the program I am using. When I directly update in SQL it appears to work, but when I submit the form from the web, fields that are locked are set to 0. This would probably be too confusing to actually explain. I would say that the solution is correct and probably works under most circumstances, just not mine :(

Comment: The only case I think this trigger won't work is if a row for a (username,gameid) pair exists in `allpoints` but not in `phpfb_picks`. In that case the missing row could be created inside the trigger, before updating.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is this scenario - On the form page there is an update being done on allpoints, but there is also a function called from another page that updates the phpfb_picks table. Maybe the allpoints is happening first, and too fast, then the phpfb_picks update happens. Anyway to delay the trigger?

Comment: Yes, you can add `DO SLEEP(number_of_seconds);` between `BEGIN` and `UPDATE`. About that scenario, I would try to delay the update on the form page until you know that the phpfb_picks update has finished (maybe using some callback); somehow there has to be a sync between the finished update of one table before beginning with the other.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. The DO SLEEP did not work, but again I think this is more of a code issue with the program. I was able to take your example and reverse it using a different variable and getting my workaround in place while I figure out the actual code issue.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
drop trigger if exists phpfb;
DELIMITER $$
create trigger phpfb after update on allpoints
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Update phpfb_picks
set points = NEW.value
where user = new.username  and gameid = new.gameid;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

for example

```
drop table if exists allpoints,phpfb_picks;

create table allpoints (username char(4),gameid int, value int);
create table phpfb_picks (user char(4),gameid int, points int);
insert into allpoints (username,gameid) values
('test',1),('test',2);

insert into phpfb_picks (user,gameid) values
('test',1),('test',1),('test',2);

update allpoints
    set value = 2 where username = 'test' and gameid = 1;
```

result

```
+------+--------+--------+
| user | gameid | points |
+------+--------+--------+
| test |      1 |      2 |
| test |      1 |      2 |
| test |      2 |      0 |
+------+--------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The issue I see here is that user and gameid together are unique, so there would never be 2 rows where the user and gameid would be duplicated